# How do I make my code skip a line if a certain driver.find_element_by_xpath isnt found

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, automation

starts here

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time

#drivers
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://www.target.com/p/plusone-waterproof-rechargeable-dual-vibrating-massager/-/A-76150669#lnk=sametab')
```

so if if ship isnt found i want addtoCart to work instead, and vise versa,

```
ship = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="viewport"]/div[4]/div/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/div/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/button')
ship.click()

addtoCart = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="addToCartButtonOrTextIdFor76150669"]')
addtoCart.click()

time.sleep(2)
cart = driver.get('https://www.target.com/cart')
```

currently trying to learn automation, want to make my own bot :)
first time posting on here

Comment: you may need a webdriverwait here, but using find_elements is easier.  It'll return a zero length array if it finds nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Does the below accomplish what you need?

```py
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException

try:
    ship = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="viewport"]/div[4]/div/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/div/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/button')
    ship.click()
except NoSuchElementException:
    try:
        addtoCart = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="addToCartButtonOrTextIdFor76150669"]')
        addtoCart.click()
    except NoSuchElementException:
        print("Can't click 'Ship' or 'Add to cart'")

time.sleep(2)
cart = driver.get('https://www.target.com/cart')
```

Comment: The condition is vice versa, you missed the part if addtocart is missing, he is building a bot

Comment: @AnmolParida I'm not sure I understand; what's the intended flow? `addtoCart` > `cart` > `ship`?

Comment: from my understanding, some online stores have add to cart and buy now option, he is trying cover all options .

Comment: @AnmolParida this code (if I understand correctly) will indeed try both, always trying `ship` first, and if that doesn't work, `addtoCart` -- what behaviour needs to change?

Comment: add one more try catch for the addtoCart